# only content part of master page in asp.net will change

Tags: asp.net

I am using Bootstrap for the website designing and while designing the master page 
I just want only content part of master page should be reloaded,header and leftside bar remains same.(should not reload with content).Can any one suggest what to do in this case. and also the leftside bar of my web changes according to user and admin login.If user login then only limited option to be and when admin login all the option in left sidebar to be .So to do this dynamically .with latest technology.i am using dotnet fromework 4.5 and i am using web forms .My application is not in MVC.

Comment: Have you tried any thing?

Comment: no i have not tried anything

Comment: try to explore [jquery .load method](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=jquery.load+method&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=ovcKWau2D-ns8AfXjpCADQ) it can help you.

Comment: @शेखर i have tried jquery.load() and its works .thank you.